# How to create foreign keys using EF Core fluent API and Value Convertors

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am using strongly typed entity Ids on my code first models, [using value convertors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#value-objects-as-keys).

To highlight the issues I'm having, here's a simplified example that achieves foreign key creation with Value Convertors using navigation properties.

```
public class BlogId: EntityId
{
    public BlogId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public BlogId Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } // Explicitly define a relationship
}

public class PostId : EntityId
{
    public PostId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public PostId Id { get; set; }
    public BlogId BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

and in the data context setup

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var blogIdConvertor = new ValueConverter<BlogId, Guid>(
        u => u.Value, v => new BlogId(v));
    
    var postIdConvertor = new ValueConverter<PostId, Guid>(
        u => u.Value, v => new PostId(v));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(u =>
    {
        u.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        u.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(blogIdConvertor);
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(u =>
    {
        u.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        u.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(postIdConvertor);
        u.Property(x => x.BlogId).HasConversion(blogIdConvertor);
    });
}
```

In the migration, the foreign key is defined correctly

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "post",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    blog_id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("pk_post", x => x.id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "fk_post_blogs_blog_temp_id",
                        column: x => x.blog_id,
                        principalTable: "blogs",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

### Problem

I need to define a foreign key relationship without specifying the navigation property on the other side of the relationship.

In the example above, that would mean the Blog model looks like this.

```
public class Blog
{
    public BlogId Id { get; set; }
    // Remove the navigation
}
```

Then I adjust the data context to use the fluid api to create a foreign key

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var blogIdConvertor = new ValueConverter<BlogId, Guid>(
        u => u.Value, v => new BlogId(v));
    
    var postIdConvertor = new ValueConverter<PostId, Guid>(
        u => u.Value, v => new PostId(v));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(u =>
    {
        u.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        u.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(blogIdConvertor);
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(u =>
    {
        u.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        u.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(postIdConvertor);
        u.Property(x => x.BlogId).HasConversion(blogIdConvertor);

        // Now use the fluent api to define the key, without the Blog side relation.
        u.HasOne(x => x.BlogId).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogId);
    });
}
```

Running the migration gives me this error:

```
The property or navigation 'BlogId' cannot be added to the entity 
type 'Post' because a property or navigation with the same name 
already exists on entity type 'Post'.
```

This is where I'm struggling to find good information how to achieve what I need.

The reason I need this is that the foreign key is required to support data integrity at the database level. I don't need it to enable an actual traversal relationship in my domain models (I'm modelling using a DDD aggregates approach)

How can one define explicit foreign keys using Value Convertors, with the fluent api, without having to "pollute" the model with relations that aren't desired?

Answer (score 1):

The answer came from the [EFCore GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26465), answered by [ajcvickers](https://github.com/ajcvickers).

---

The fundamental problem in the code above is that it is trying to use an FK property as a navigation property. Instead, if there is no navigation, then leave it out. For example:

`u.HasOne<Blog>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogId);`

Here's a full example. Make sure your value objects implement equality correctly. Alternately, consider using readonly structs.

```
public abstract class EntityId
{
    protected EntityId(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Guid Value { get; }

    private bool Equals(EntityId other)
        => Value.Equals(other.Value);

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((EntityId)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
        => Value.GetHashCode();
}

public class BlogId : EntityId
{
    public BlogId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public BlogId Id { get; set; }
}

public class PostId : EntityId
{
    public PostId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public PostId Id { get; set; }
    public BlogId BlogId { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(Your.ConnectionString)
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var blogIdConvertor = new ValueConverter<BlogId, Guid>(
            u => u.Value, v => new BlogId(v));

        var postIdConvertor = new ValueConverter<PostId, Guid>(
            u => u.Value, v => new PostId(v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(u =>
        {
            u.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(blogIdConvertor);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(u =>
        {
            u.Property(x => x.Id).HasConversion(postIdConvertor);
            u.Property(x => x.BlogId).HasConversion(blogIdConvertor);

            u.HasOne<Blog>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogId);
        });
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var context = new SomeDbContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var blog = new Blog {Id = new(Guid.NewGuid())};
            var post = new Post {Id = new(Guid.NewGuid()), BlogId = blog.Id};
            context.AddRange(blog, post);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using(var context = new SomeDbContext())
        {
            var post = context.Set<Post>().Single();
            var blog = context.Set<Blog>().Find(post.BlogId);

            Console.WriteLine(blog.Id.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(post.Id.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You removed the Blog.Posts navigation which OP attempted to use. Does your answer work with any forms of navigation?